# Search one smaller and one bigger number then serach term?

Tags: python

I have a list in the python and I want to find out the search term with conditions one smaller and one bigger number the search term.

```py
list =  [2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 12, 19, 22, 34]
search_term = 10
```

I want to get one smaller and one bigger term next to the search term from the list.

The expected result should be

```py
output = [7, 9]
```

Comment: Do you want to get the first elements `> 10` and `< 10`?

Comment: What is your expected output for your example?

Comment: Your question isn't clear and you haven't provided expected output (*why not?*) but I think you want `min(x for x in list if x > search_term)` etc. And please don't use `list` as a variable name because it usually means something else in Python. Doing that will work but will eventually come back to bite you.

Comment: The question is clear. He wants to find the `9` and `12`. The two numbers closest to 10.

Comment: @Thomas - is it? And what happens when there isn't a number smaller/bigger?  You could say 2 is one of the ones smaller and 34 is one of the ones bigger, or you could say you're searching for `9` and `11` (10-1 and 10+1)

Comment: Why is the result [7, 9]?  I would lhave expected [9, 12] since 9 is the first number below search_term and 12 is the first number after the search_term.

Answer (score 1):

Edit for `[7, 9]`

Search up until you are `>= search_term`, then print last 2 values:

```py
# Don't use class names (list) as variables
lst = [2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 12, 19, 22, 34]
search_term = 10

# Sort list for iterating. lst is now sorted
lst.sort()
index = 0

# Get index of values. Stop when item >= search_term
for i, item in enumerate(lst[1:]):
    if item >= search_term:
        index = i
        break

output = [lst[index-1], lst[index]]
```

```
>>> output
[7, 9]
```

---

**This was for printing value before and after `search_term`**

<sup>There was no output, and this was a guess at what OP wanted</sup>

You can iterate over your `lst` and check for `>` and `<` `search_term`:

- This works for non-empty `lists`

```
# Don't use class names (list) as variables
lst = [2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 12, 19, 22, 34]
search_term = 10

# Sort
lst.sort()
last = lst[0]
index = 0

# Get item before
for i, item in enumerate(lst[1:]):
    if item < search_term:
        last = item
        index = i
    else:
        break

print(f'Before = {last}')

# Get item after
try:
    for item in lst[index+1:]:
        if item >= search_term:
            last = item
            break
except IndexError:
    pass
    # You don't have any values after the before value

print(f'After  = {last}')
```

```
Before = 9
After  = 12
```

An exception may be the case of:

```
>>> lst = [1, 10]
>>> search_term = 10
```

Which prints

```
Before = 1
After  = 10
```

Comment: I think you can avoid the second loop, the first value `>10` is just after the last `<10` since the list is sorted. Maybe just add a condition if there is `10` in the list depending in what OP search

Comment: @MariusROBERT The second loop is to check for when the list has multiple `search_term`s. Like `[1, 10, 10, 10, 100]`. So it may not just be after `10`.

Comment: What about change the `else` to `elif item > search_term` ?

Comment: @MariusROBERT why's that? (`elif item > search_term`)

Comment: To avoid using a second for loop

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
l =  [2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 12, 19, 22, 34]
search_term = 10    
 

tmp = [max([t for t in l if t <= search_term])] # smaller than search
tmp.append(min([t for t in l if t >= search_term])) #bigger than search

print("nearest smaller :",tmp[0]) 
print("nearest bigger :",tmp[1])
```

Output:

```
nearest smaller : 9
nearest bigger : 12
```